# cURL XML Post issue

Tags: php, xml, curl

Im posting some XML to a webservice, the code I have written works in all other cases just not in this instance.

This is my code;

```
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 45); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml")); 

$result = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch);

return $result;
```

It keeps returning a 500 internal server error which is the same as if you go direct to the url so it's like the POST data isn't being sent. But I haven't check the content length and it seems to be..

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try just this

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_string); // NOTE used $xml_string to indicate its just a text string of XML format
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, I've just tried this, and it is giving me the same error 500 error

Comment: post it to a dump script and var_dump($_POST) in it to double check, then echo $result. Is $string (or in my case $xml_string) empty?

Comment: add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); incase the site redirects to another page